# DocuSign Attachments relate to [DocuSign Status object] to my custom object record

Tags: trigger, visualforce-component, docusign

I would like to know how I can relate Attachments related to DocuSign Status object to a record on a custom object where I triggered the Docusign.

I don't see any way to set that every document that has been sent and completed by the end customer, goes to the record what triggered the envelope screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your docusign account Click on your DP at top right corner and select switch to classic first.

Next once you have been switched to classic , again click on your icon select preferences-->go to New Admin-->Connect -->Salesforce there you can find this below Image, Where you can select your salesforce custom Object to add the docusign.

Before you do that Add the Docusign status sobject as related list to your custom object.

[image]

Comment: Thx very much, I figured out before I had a silly mistake that stuck the process.